# Removing a dependency in a constructor using PHPunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

While trying to get a legacy codebase under test, I've come across an object that does the following:

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct($someargs)
    {
        $this->bar = new Bar();
        // [lots more code]
    }
}
```

Bar in this instance has a constructor that does some Bad Things e.g. connecting to a database.  I'm trying to concentrate on getting this Foo class under test so changed it to something like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct($someargs)
    {
        $this->bar = $this->getBarInstance();
        // [lots more code]
    }

    protected function getBarInstance()
    {
        return new Bar();
    }
}
```

And have attempted to test it via the following PHPUnit test:

```
class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testInstance()
    {

        $bar = $this->getMock('Bar');
        $foo = $this->getMock('Foo', array('getBarInstance'));
        $foo->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getBarInstance')
            ->will($this->returnValue($bar));

    }

}
```

However this doesn't work - the constructor of Foo() is called before my ->expects() is added, so the mocked getBarInstance() method returns a null.

Is there any way of unlinking this dependency without having to refactor the way the class uses constructors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `$callOriginalConstructor` argument of `getMock()`. Set it to `false`. It's the fifth argument of the method. Look it up here: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/api.html#api.testcase.tables.api

Actually, hold on. You want to pass a mock to a mock? If you really want this, then use the third argument of `getMock` which represents the arguments to the constructor. There you can pass the mock of `Bar` to the mock of `Foo`.

Comment: But the constructor does 'stuff', should that be split out into a separate method?

Comment: I've just edited the answer. You can pass a mock to the mock, but I don't really see the point.

Comment: And yes, if the constructor does stuff you should move that code into a separate method. Constructor should usually just set up the state of the object, like setting the instance fields to certain values, usually passed as arguments to the constructor.

Comment: I'm doing a partial mock of Foo and only overriding the method that contains the dependency, as I've not got a better way of injecting in the Bar yet (hopefully once this is under test I can refactor it a bit).

Comment: Use the third argument of `getMock('Foo')` in order to pass the mock of `Bar`. It should work.